# Change topic name used by Debezium connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I would like to change the topic names using a Debezium connector, as I would like the topics not to be named with the default name "server.schema.table".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use various [Kafka Connect transforms](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/overview.html) for setting the topic name.

- `InsertField` to set static topic name
- `ExtractField` + `ExtractTopic` for using some property of the record
- `RegexRouter` for modifying the topic name based on a pattern ; for example, removing `server.schema.` prefix
- One of your own

Comment: i am using ksql, what lines of code should i add to connector creation to make sm2.ingestion.surf.db.TableName use as default name for topic creation?

Comment: Can you please show your connector config in your question? Ksql embeds Connect. `transforms` is the Connector property. The InsertField type will set a static topic name... Go through the links for examples

Comment: Or if you're trying to prefix the database name with `sm2.ingestion.surf`, use RegexRouter